# include bootstrap role attribute in rails form helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, twitter-bootstrap, role, form-helpers

Twitter Bootstrap has this role attribute for forms:

```
<form role="form">
```

How can I include the role attribute in Rails form helpers? I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
<%= form_for @user, class: "form-horizontal", role: "form" do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to specify it as an html option:

```
<%= form_for @user, html: {class: "form-horizontal", role: "form"} do |f| %>
```

Comment: Glad to hear! Can you please accept the answer so others know it's been answered?

Comment: This is just to say that what is shown in this answer works, and that with parentheses it does not: `<%= form_for(@user), ...` -- It yields `syntax error, unexpected tLABEL` and `syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block, expecting keyword_end`.

Comment: @user664833 if you wanted to use parens, you'd have to wrap everything, not just the `@user` object.

Comment: How can I add "role" using "form_tag"?

Answer (score 1):

`form_for` and `form_tag` have to be used differently:

**form_for:**

```
<%= form_for @user, html: { class: "form-horizontal", role: "form" } do |f| %>
```

**form_tag:**

```
<%= form_tag some_path, class: "form-horizontal", role: "form" do |f| %>
```