# Form_tag with Role in Rails 3 to work with Bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, twitter-bootstrap, role

Twitter Bootstrap uses the role attribute in forms, e.g. `<form role="form">`.

How can I include the role attribute using the Rails 3 form helper form_tag?

This is similar to the question [include bootstrap role attribute in rails form helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19622056/include-bootstrap-role-attribute-in-rails-form-helper) but for form_tag instead of form_for

Comment: Have you tried to go with simple 'role: "form"'? This is what rails docs / code say about passing HTML arguments to this tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below should work:

```
<%= form_tag your_path_url, { class: 'form-class', id: 'form-id', role: 'form', method: 'post' } do %>
 <% #your form content here %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

After some trial and error, this worked:

```
 <%= form_tag "/test", {:class => 'form-inline', :role => 'form'} do %>
```